# Why doesn't my push() function work?

Tags: javascript, meteor, foreach

I have a weird issue at hand. I have a `push()` function in my code that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone kindly tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
var viewStatisticsArray= [];

var viewStatistics = buyList.find("Pq9Kgrd4Haa5vjQov");

viewStatistics.forEach(function(itemName){
  viewStatisticsArray.push({statesDate: Date(), nrOfViews: itemName.noOfViews});
  console.log("Item Stats is: " ,...viewStatisticsArray); 
});
```

The console prints out the below.

> Item Stats is:  Object {statesDate: "Mon Mar 20 2017 22:19:28 GMT+0300 (EAT)", nrOfViews: 2}

Kindly point out why the `push()` function doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `viewStatistics` and what are those backticks in your code? What did you expect to happen and how is the result different?

Comment: It is working. There is a single item in your array, and the log is logging it. You've used the spread operator, so each element in the array will be separately printed.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan it's not working like I'd like it to. I'd like each item to be added to the array each time I run the script.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ...what happens instead is that nothing is added to the array but rather the item in the array is updated with the latest details, so statesDate: is the my current date and time while the  nrOfViews: keeps getting updated to the current number of views.

Comment: Include what you have for input (what's in the `viewStatistics` array?) and what you expect for output. Right now, your code shows a `forEach` function with a syntax error because of the backticks in the code, as pointed out by @MasterAM half an hour ago. You're also logging from within the `forEach`, so it will log on every iteration. You may want to log after the iteration is complete. `statesDate` will always be the current date because you're setting it to `Date()`, which returns the current date...

Comment: @MasterAM. The backticks infront an array, will prints out an array as an object, this way you are able to see the contents of each object. So instead of [Object] you'll see the objects contents. I expected the push() function to ADD contents to the array, instead the push() function seems to keeps on updating the statesDate: with the latetest date and nrOfViews: with the latest number of views. No items are added to the array. :-( help!

Comment: Earlier you said "I'd like each item to be added to the array each time I run the script".  The way the code is written, each time this snippet of javascript is executed you will always start out with an empty `viewStatisticsArray` (e.g. var viewStatisticsArray= [];).  If you want the data to persist then define the array somewhere else outside the scope of this file and don't re-assign it to an empty array each time.

Comment: @MasterAM The reason I iterate the `viewStatistics` is solely to get the `nrOfViews` (number of visits a page has gotten) contents. My intention is to log these details into the `viewStatisticsArray` array.  The expected result should look something like this:  `{statesDate: "Mon Mar 20 2017 23:31:23 GMT+0300 (EAT)", nrOfViews: 2}`, `{statesDate: "Mon Mar 20 2017 23:34:23 GMT+0300 (EAT)", nrOfViews: 20}` etc. Sadly it always looks like this each time i run the script:  `{statesDate: "Mon Mar 20 2017 00:07:23 GMT+0300 (EAT)", nrOfViews: 40}`

Comment: See my answer.  The problem is that you are clobbering your array each time your snippet runs (since you are setting `viewStatisticsArray= []`)

Comment: @jordanwillis Oh thanks for pointing this out for me! This resolved the problem for me!

Comment: Cool.  I documented everything in my answer below.  See the answer for more details.

Comment: BTW, you confused _back ticks_ (\`) with _ellipsis_ (`...`). The back ticks were likely a typo edited out by Michael.

Answer (score 2):

This code looks like it is doing exactly what was written to do.

```
var viewStatisticsArray= [];

var viewStatistics = buyList.find("Pq9Kgrd4Haa5vjQov");

viewStatistics.forEach(function(itemName){
  viewStatisticsArray.push({statesDate: Date(), nrOfViews: itemName.noOfViews});
  console.log("Item Stats is: " ,...viewStatisticsArray); 
});
```

When the snippet is executed, the `viewStatisticsArray` is empty and then you are only ever adding 1 item to the array because `buyList.find()` will only ever return a cursor with 1 record (since you are passing an `_id` to the Meteor Collection.find method).

When it runs again, the array is re-set to an empty array (e.g. `var viewStatisticsArray= []`) and it again pushes a single record into the array.

Since you mentioned you want to array to grow over time then it means you need to persist the data.  If you want to persist the data in `viewStatisticsArray` (such that it's length grows over time), then you must define this array elsewhere (somewhere outside the scope of this snippet) and be sure not to re-assign to var to an empty array when this runs (like you are doing now).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the push() function only appends to an array only if there is an existing array with content. Since Appending to the array was my intention,I got the contents of the already existing array then appended by using the push() function

```
var viewStatisticsArray= [];
var viewStatistics = buyList.find("Pq9Kgrd4Haa5vjQov");

viewStatistics.forEach(function(itemName){

viewStatisticsArray = [,...itemName.viewStatisticsArray];
```

The code above, fills the **viewStatisticsArray** array with the initial array contents, while the below appends to the **viewStatisticsArray** array.

```
 viewStatisticsArray.push({statesDate: Date(), nrOfViews: itemName.noOfViews});  
    });
```

Credit to @ jordanwillis for pointing me in the right direction.